# How to make video with full height on half desktop screen?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

page url: https://dtlapi.portal.azure-api.net/how-distro-integrates-with-data

I have an video with 4096x2160 pixel and I am displaying this video on my left half screen. I want to display centered part of video with full height.

I have tried everything but not found any solution. Any help will appreciate.

Comment: its not clear what you want , but i think your looking for `height: 50vh;`

Comment: I want the display video with full height.

Comment: so you want the video to contain the full height and width of half the screen?

Comment: Height:50vh is not working

Comment: @media (min-width: 1025px)
#myVideo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

Comment: yes right @Ylama

Comment: Check now, There is space on top and bottom of video, this is not what I want

Comment: i see .. let me see what i can do

Comment: look at my awser should do the trick. pleasure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

Sets the element height to full screen, and then fits the video to cover the full height.

```
 @media (min-width: 1025px)
  #myVideo {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   object-fit: cover;
 }
```

Comment: sure no problem. pleasure. @SonuTyagi